# Insert a snippet from a Visual Studio macro

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, macros, code-snippets

I have a situation where I want to run a Visual Studio macro that has the user type something in an InputBox, then inserts a snippet and includes that text somewhere in it.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to insert the snippet from macro code.  It seems like it'd be something like

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.InvokeSnippetFromShortcut")
```

or

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.InvokeSnippetFromShortcut", "theSnippetName")
```

but those don't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a snippet with the following code.

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "snippetshortcut"
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.InsertTab")
```

If you are using VS 2010 then you will need to call DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.InsertTab") twice.

Comment: Holy cow, you're right.  And now that I see it, I realize that I probably could have discovered it by recording a macro, had I thought of it.  Thanks!  ...Now if only I could remember what I was doing sixteen months ago that I wanted to know this for.  :)

Comment: What I needed this for was inserting a snippet but populating some of the literals with calculated values (like today's date).

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide where this code should be selected. To insert text in current text selection you need to use the following code:

```
Dim textSelection As EnvDTE.TextSelection
textSelection = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection          
textSelection.Insert(MyTextVarHere)
```

Comment: I want to insert a *snippet*.  Not just some text.  *Snippet* has a specific meaning in Visual Studio.